# Count lowercase and uppercase then return it as a tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to implement a function called countLowerUpper which takes a String and count lower and uppercases and return it as a tuple. For example : `countLowerUpper "TeST"` should return `(1,3)`. I don't know how to return a tuple properly. I am forced to use `countLowerUpper :: String-> (Int,Int)`. I can't change it.

```
import Data.Char
countLowerUpper :: String-> (Int,Int)
countLowerUpper = (length . filter (isLower),length . filter(isUpper))
```

EDIT After received help I change my code to:

```
import Data.Char

countLowerUpper :: String-> (Int,Int)
countLowerUpper str  = (lowerCount,upperCount)
    where lowerCount =length . filter(isLower)
          upperCount =length . filter(isUpper)
```

But still have got error:

```
 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘[Char] -> Int’
    • Probable cause: ‘upperCount’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: upperCount
      In the expression: (lowerCount, upperCount)
      In an equation for ‘countLowerUpper’:
          countLowerUpper str
            = (lowerCount, upperCount)
            where
                lowerCount = length . filter (isLower)
                upperCount = length . filter (isUpper)
  |
4 | countLowerUpper str  = (lowerCount,upperCount)   |
```

I know that isLower don't have got any argument but I don't know what to use. Maybe str? Or use head and tail of string?

Comment: Break things up. You are really close. Don't try and get fancy with point-free notation.

Comment: Trying make things done for about 3 hours. I will be delighted if you can help me a little more ;).

Comment: "I know that isLower don't have got any argument but I don't know what to use." Instead of thinking about the arguments to `isLower`, try thinking about the arguments to `filter`. It takes two of them. How many are you passing to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Char

countLowerUpper :: String -> (Int,Int)
countLowerUpper str = (lowerCount,upperCount)
    where lowerCount = undefined
          upperCount = undefined
```

You can do this.

Comment: lowerCount and upperCount should have something like this? ```length . filter (isLower)```?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work :/. I am wondering where i should put this str. I tried ```length . filter (isLower str)``` but it doesn't work and doesn't make sense I think.

Comment: "it doesn't work", helps no one, least of all you. What's the error? Include what you tried, and the error in your problem report above. Not in comments.

Comment: Updated post, I'm trying to understand the problem but I'm new to functional programming and don't know how to build tuples by now.

Comment: Your functions need a value. The name of the value in this case is `str`. The problem isn't not being able to build tuples but rather understanding the error message you see. This will come in time, you're doing fine.

Comment: I get that str is a string and function isLower needs char. What i should do? Something like head and tail? How can I get suitable value for isLower and isUpper?

Comment: what is the type of `filter`? what is the type of `filter isLower` ? What is the type of `str`?